# In OpenZeppelin's implementation of ERC20's transferFrom, why is _transfer() called before withdrawer allowance is checked

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

This is taken from OpenZeppelin's ERC20 `transferFrom` implementation:

```
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a reason why `_transfer` is called prior to checking the withdrawer (`msg.sender`) allowance?

Would `transferFrom` still work correctly if the allowance `require` check was done first instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found discussion about the same topic on the OpenZeppelin [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2030) and the **author of the code confirms the order is irrelevant** in the context of ERC-20.

> *In the case of ERC20, the order is irrelevant because _transfer and _approve are independent and never call any other contract: they are executed atomically.*

Plus he states it's important to keep the order stabilized for the case when someone wants to override the functions.

> *However, this is very relevant for users that intent to override _transfer or _approve with their own implementations: we should be clear about the order in which these things happen.*

Source: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2030#issuecomment-568487500

---

So assuming you're not using custom logic in overriden `_transfer()` and `_approve()` internal functions, the `transferFrom()` would still work correctly if you switched the order.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Since it's irrelevant, it's odd they didn't choose the ordering with the most sense semantically. 

ERC1155's implementation follows this pattern, however, which is nice: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the same thing, then I found this discussion
[https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/in-erc20-tranferfrom-why-transfer-before-checking-allowance/5312/3] It gives more details and shed the light on the reasoning behind it.